# Как модифицировать Secure Preferences?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

В новой версии Сhrome 37.0.2062.120 появился новый Secure Preferences файл, теперь 2 файла Secure Preferences и Preferences вместо одного. Как модифицировать Secure Preferences теперь, ведь при изменениях пишется защитный код?

Secure Preferences файл:

```
{
"extensions": {
"settings": {
}
},
"protection": {
"macs": {
"browser": {
"show_home_button": "6F07A285FE2C96A4DFF2CA4CA5783179E9C811CBC11DCDDBFB134EDCF6A3744C"
},
"extensions": {
"aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc": "11D619FC1E8DD99DF100E17B1D95F64D3C46BF6A5538D6031C80608720D9BDAD",
}
}
}
}
```

Что за защитный protect mac код "11D619FC1E8DD99DF100E17B1D95F64D3C46BF6A5538D6031C80608720D9BDAD"? Может, это хэш строк, какая кодировка? Как корректно генерировать этот код?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать спросить на форуме гугла принцип работы.
Я пока тоже не понял, как он работает.
Хотя вроде бы этот хэш напоминает метод HMAC (похож на SHA-1), только с ключом.

Answer (score 0):

Это хэш от значения всех полей, указаных в настроках расширения + какой-то ИД машины, видимо, защита от умников, которые по тихому ставили расширения через файл Preferences. Копаюсь в исходниках хроимума, пока не понял, как генерится.